# Qual è il significato di "trucchi sorridenti dell’ossequio alle leggi"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Mi sentivo ormai parte di un potere legittimo, universalmente ammirato, aureolato di cultura d’alto livello, e volevo vedere quale veste chiassosa si stava dando il potere che avevo avuto sotto gli occhi fin dall’infanzia, il volgare piacere della sopraffazione, la pratica impunita del crimine, i trucchi sorridenti dell’ossequio alle leggi, lo sfoggio dello sperpero com’erano incarnati dai fratelli Solara.

I fratelli Solara sono i "guappi" del rione di Napoli dove la narratrice era cresciuta.

Malgrado abbia cercato il vocabolo "ossequio" in alcuni dizionari, non riesco a capire il significato dell'espressione "i trucchi sorridenti dell’ossequio alle leggi". In particolare, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ossequio/) ho trovato questa spiegazione

> burocr., *in ossequio alla legge, alle disposizioni*, e sim., in obbedienza, in conformità a esse

ma mi sembra contradittoria con quello che si può più o meno capire dal contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "i trucchi sorridenti dell’ossequio alle leggi" nel brano precedente?

Comment: A naso, direi che qui la Ferrante, per una svista o per un uso estremamente esteso del termine, usi “sorridere” come se significasse “irridere”, parlando cioè di trucchi che si fanno beffe del rispetto della legge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplice interpretazione possibile.

La prima, e più probabile, è quella suggerita da DaG, ovvero che "i trucchi" (sotterfugi) sberleffino le leggi ed il sottostarvi.

L'altra è che i trucchi siano moralmente inaccettabili, ma non strettamente illegali (le zone grigie della legge), e quindi possono sorridere ed essere ossequiosi della legge, sebbene essendo scorretti.